# AngularJS - ng-change as an option in a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to add an `ng-change` function into a custom directive but I'm not sure if `ng-change` will go inside the template or into link function, additionally I'd like to make the `ng-change` optional (calling '

<text-edit-in-place value="loan.due_date" change="checkException"
 param="foobar">

' would add the `checkException('foobar')` function where leaving out change= & param= would not run any `ng-change`).

```
function TextEditInPlaceDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            value: '='
        },
        template: '<span ng-click="edit()" ng-show="!editing">{{ value}}</span><input ng-model="value" ng-blur="onBlur()" ng-show="editing"></input>',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            var inputElement = element.find('input');

            // reference the input element
            element.addClass('edit-in-place');

            // Initially, we're not editing.
            $scope.editing = false;

            // ng-click handler to activate edit-in-place
            $scope.edit = function() {
                $scope.editing = true;

                // element not visible until digest complete
                // timeout causes this to run after digest
                setTimeout(function() {
                    inputElement[0].focus();
                });
            };

            $scope.onBlur = function() {
                $scope.editing = false;
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Help would appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a format similar to [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0cudzyw/2/)

In that format, you can define the function within the directive, then specify whether or not you want the function to be called.

Example:

```
<test-change value="blah" check-exceptions="true" ng-model="foo"/>
```

That should be the most straight-forward way to do it.

Then you can define the function within the link function in the directive.

Comment: never thought of ngChange in the scope ... however, I am not sure what replaces your three dots inside if($scope.ngChange){ ... }.

Comment: @mirir137, I added your code both with the if and without the if and had 764 console errors -- all the same about an inject error.