# Angular: Propagate a controller function to a directive

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a simple function in my controller that, when called in my template, works perfectly, as below:

In my controller:

```
$scope.save = function(arg){ ... }
```

In my template:

```
<input ng-model="namespace" ng-change="save(namespace)">
```

So I created a directive, and this function was not propagated anymore:

In my directive:

```
.directive('genericField', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      namespace: '=',
      ngChange: '&',
      save: '&',
    },
    template: '<input ng-model="namespace" ng-change="save(namespace)">',
  }
})
```

And in my template:

```
<generic-field namespace="name"></generic-field>
```

What am I missing here? Any light on this problem?
Thank you

Comment: can you provide fiddle ?

Comment: doesn't seem like you pass the save function to the directive. try <generic-field namespace="name" save="save"></generic-field>

Comment: You are missing a lot of things actually, like  restrict: 'AE' and other small things. I tried to reproduce your request into a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21716/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - ng-change as an option in a custom directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516256/angularjs-ng-change-as-an-option-in-a-custom-directive)

Comment: You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/2157/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your codes as below.
 Directive :

```
.directive('genericField', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      save: '&'
    },
    template: '<input ng-model="namespace" ng-change="save({arg : namespace})">',
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
<generic-field namespace="name" save="save(arg)"></generic-field>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/2158/)**